# How can I hide everything on a page except for one div, and then show it once a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide everything on my page except a single div. Tried `visibility: hidden;` but the other divs still take up space.

Any help?

Comment: _“The `visibility` CSS property shows or hides an element without changing the layout of a document. To both hide an element **and remove it from the document layout, set the `display` property to `none`** instead of using `visibility`.”_ — from [the documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: none;` should do the trick.

if you want to get a div to show when you click a button, you could do

```js
function showHidden(){
  document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#hidden{display: none;}
```

```html
<div> click the button to show another div </div>
<button onclick="showHidden()">button</button>
<div id="hidden">hidden div</div>
```

hopefully that helped.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `visibility: hidden;`, try `display: none;`. This way the blocks don't take up space.

Find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)